# How to add unique links to google maps markers

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I'm just trying to figure out how to add unique links to each Google Maps Marker.

I tried adding a 3rd value to each locations array item and then adding url:locations[2] to the new google maps class but it just broke the map.

I have the following JS...

```
            function initMap() {

            var centerPoint = { lat: 51.6856885, lng: -3.6304398 };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: centerPoint,
                styles: [{ "featureType": "all", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [{ "color": "#ffffff" }] }, { "featureType": "all", "elementType": "labels.text.stroke", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }, { "color": "#424b5b" }, { "weight": 2 }, { "gamma": "1" }] }, { "featureType": "all", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }] }, { "featureType": "administrative", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{ "weight": 0.6 }, { "color": "#545b6b" }, { "gamma": "0" }] }, { "featureType": "landscape", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{ "color": "#545b6b" }, { "gamma": "1" }, { "weight": "10" }] }, { "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{ "color": "#666c7b" }] }, { "featureType": "poi.park", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{ "color": "#545b6b" }] }, { "featureType": "road", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{ "color": "#424a5b" }, { "lightness": "0" }] }, { "featureType": "transit", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{ "color": "#666c7b" }] }, { "featureType": "water", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{ "color": "#2e3546" }] }]
            });

            // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
            var labels = '';

            // Add some markers to the map.
            // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
            // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
            // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
            var markers = locations.map(function (location, i) {
                return new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    label: labels[i % labels.length]
                });
            });

            // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
                { imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m' });
        }
        var locations = [
          { lat: 51.5474973, lng: -3.5777395 },
          { lat: 51.4668561, lng: -3.1689607 },
          { lat: 51.6156059, lng: -3.6934229 },
          { lat: 51.5250486, lng: -3.6780919 },

          { lat: 51.6428655, lng: -3.9859831 },
          { lat: 51.5447132, lng: -3.5961878 },
          { lat: 51.5678233, lng: -3.2866061 },
          { lat: 51.5122641, lng: -3.5073934 },
          { lat: 51.4668561, lng: -3.1689607 }
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly. You could could add a third element to your locations array items you just couldn't use it directly as is. You could have

```
var locations = [
      { latLng:{lat: 51.5474973, lng: -3.5777395},url:'google.com' }
]
```

then in your function do this

```
return new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location.latLng,
    url: location.url,
    label: labels[i % labels.length]
});
```

then the url would be in each marker object. So on a click of a marker you could call this.url and get the url.

Comment: Did this but then I click on the icon in the map and it still doesn't actually do anything unfortunately.

Comment: how are you setting up your click functions? you could add that withing your loop

Comment: like this...

var markers = locations.map(function (location, i) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: 51.5474973, lng: -3.5777395 },
        url: location.url,
        label: labels[i % labels.length]
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        console.log(this.url);
        //or if you want it to redirect
 location.href = this.url;
    });
 return marker;
});